# Get Power BI reports in Share Point Office 365 Site

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365, powerbi

I have **Office 365 Enterprise E3** Licenses with **Power BI Pro** .

I have created Data sets and Report in PowerBI by using Office 365 Document Library excels,but i am not able to get those report in Office 365.

I want to know how to get reports created in PowerBi to Office 365 sites.

Any help will highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is on the backlog.  You can use a solution built by our partners over at DevScope.  In the Office app store you'll find [Power BI Tiles for SharePoint](https://store.office.com/power-bi-tiles-for-sharepoint-WA104379750.aspx) app.

To stay up to date on this feature [vote for this feature on our UserVoice page](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/6740156-embed-in-sharepoint-office365).